# a function that is not measurable but its square is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Question:
Give an example of a function $f$ on $X$ to $R$ which is not $X$ measurable, but is such that the functions $|f|$ and $f^2$ are measurable.

To me, $|f|$ is measurable and $f^2$ is measurable are equivalent. However, I have no idea how to construct the example. Any hint?

Comment: Consider a function that only takes values $1$ and $-1$.

Comment: @Andres Caicedo You mean the function maps all the values of X to {-1,1}?

Comment: @scitamehtam: Yes.

Comment: For non-measurability, consider the equivalence relation $x\sim y$ if and only if $x-y \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @Mnifldz Thanks! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set this is helpful to me.